# iOS add observer to viewcontroller before it's initiated

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my iOS scenario

1.The app gets a remote notification

2.In Appdelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I post a notification

```
        if let options = launchOptions{
        if let remoteNotification = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]{

             //post notification
        }
    }
```

3. The App's root view controller is a navigation controller whose root controller is the target controller.
4. In the target controller's viewDidLoad I add an observer to get this notification.

The Problem is that the target view controller is not created when the notification is posted. So the target view controller can not get the notification at all. How to solve this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this method? Typically you don't want to observe anything on a view controller before it's about to be presented on the screen as it can have all sorts of consequences from accessing the VC's view too early (assuming that the notification will mean UI changes). Do you have more details about your scenario?

Comment: @dlbuckley  In fact my app has only one viewcontroller. If the app is not launched from remote notification, it has one UI. If it's, it has another UI. That's the problem

Comment: @dlbuckley Any suggestions? Thx

Comment: Can't you just detect which notification you receive in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and then choose which VC is the root VC of the navigation controller? Then you don't have to post any notifications yourself at all. Or maybe I misunderstand what you are after here?

Answer (score 1):

You can save your notification as a reference in AppDelegate like:

```
var notification : NSNotifcation?
```

And set it's value when you receive your notification. Then in your view controller check whether `AppDelegate`'s `notification` property has a value.

```
if let notification = (UIApplicaton.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).notification{
  // handle your notification
}
```

Also don't forget to set `notification` value to `nil` when you're done with it.

Comment: This adds a dependency on the app delegate within the VC. Doing things like this leads to spaghetti code that no-one wants to maintain. If anything there should be a delegate pattern used rather than accessing the AppDelegate directly. That way the VC can be used anywhere and can have a notification passed to it by anything. Decoupled, maintainable, and above all else, testable.